# Realm Asynchronous Transactions Order Structure in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, transactions, realm

I want to execute below methods **in order**. That means, if A methods ends, B starts. If B ends C starts and so forth.

```
public void InitializeAPI {
    public static void init_A(Context mContext) {
        Realm.init(mContext);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                // Some working is here.
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            // Some proceesing lines are here.
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            Log.d("AsyncTransaction", "ERROR");
        });
        // And there are lots of other TransactionAsync() line in this methods.
    }
    public static void init_B(Context mContext) {...}
    public static void init_C(Context mContext) {...}
    // and So many initialize methods.
}
```

As you can see, when I execute `init_A(Context)`, Async Transaction will be in background.

But the problem is `init_B` needs to be executed after `init_A` ending. `init_C` also. How can I design this matter??

Of course, I know that there is `Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess()` But, If I write `init_B` in `Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess()` at `init_A`, I think that codes won't be neat or good to Maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
 realm.beginTransaction();

  //... add or update objects here ...

 realm.commitTransaction();
```

instead of a async call.
It will ensure that code will work synchronously.

Hope it helps..!

Comment: (Sorry for late reply)But, as you can see the name of class, `InitializeAPI`, there are lots of HTTP request and parsing codes. If it is not Async, doesn't it have low performance(low speed)?

Comment: There are almost 600 requests.

Comment: try to check the code for method **executeTransactionAsync** in RealM lib,you will see they are using the same realm.beginTransaction(); and realm.commitTransaction(); and yes 600 is a huge number but check executeTransactionAsync method's code first. (use ctrl+click)

Answer (score 1):

you could send a message though handler in the `OnSuccess` to trigger the `init_B`. But that doesn't look much better. So if you want to do the initialization without blocking the UI, creating your own thread might a good choice.

```
public void InitializeAPI {
    public static void init_A(Context mContext) {
        Realm.init(mContext);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        // Write data
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
    public static void init_B(Context mContext) {...}
    public static void init_C(Context mContext) {...}
    // and So many initialize methods.
    public static void init() {
        init_A();
        init_B();
        init_C();
        //...
    }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InitializeAPI.init();
        // Notify the main thread that initialization is done.
        handler.post(initialziedRunnable);
    }
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: Oh, actually I am not familiar with `Handler` So, I will study it more :) May I add more comment after studying it?